# why jquery mobile pages are loading twice

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
I am using jquery mobile 1.4.2
```

The pages of our jquery mobile websites are loading twice.
    When the scroll bar is at the bottom of the page then when i reload a frame the scroll bar is at the same position as it was before i reload a frame(withou JQM).
     Here is jsfidlle without jquery mobile it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/mfqne4rs/2/

```
Here is a jsfidlle with jqm.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p8gesf1g/

When the scroll bar is at the bottom of the page then when i reload a frame the scroll bar is not at the same position  as it was before i reload a frame i mean its going up(with JQM).

I want this to work as a jsfiddle which works without jqm.